# C++ Can't get process id (windows)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

I have a function like this to get a process' id by it's name, however it always returns 0 with every process i try:

```
DWORD GetProcessId(std::string ProcessName)
{
HANDLE hsnap;
PROCESSENTRY32 pt;
DWORD PiD;
hsnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
pt.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
do {
    if (!strcmp(pt.szExeFile, ProcessName.c_str())) {
        CloseHandle(hsnap);
        PiD = pt.th32ProcessID;
        return PiD;
        if (PiD != NULL) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
} while (Process32Next(hsnap, &pt));
return 1;
}
```

and main function:

```
int main()
{
DWORD pid = GetProcessId("calc.exe");
std::cout << pid;
if (pid == 0) { printf("error 1"); getchar(); }//error
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

Firstly, [`GetProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683215(v=vs.85).aspx) is the name of a Windows API function, that takes a single `HANDLE` as a parameter. `HANDLE` is usually defined as `void*` and so what this means is that any pointer will satisfy the function signature.

Your own `GetProcessId` takes a `std::string` but you're calling it by passing it a pointer to a string constant. Normally this would be OK, a `std::string` can be constructed from that, but because the Windows API version of `GetProcessId` already matches the function signature the compiler calls that in preference. So basically your own function is never actually being called.

There are also a couple of problems with your own function. Firstly, your first iteration through the loop is comparing against garbage memory - you're forgetting to call `Process32First`, and so `pt` is uninitialised the first time through. Secondly, if the process isn't found you're leaking the `hsnap` handle.

Try the following:

```
DWORD MyGetProcessId(LPCTSTR ProcessName) // non-conflicting function name
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pt;
    HANDLE hsnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    pt.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    if (Process32First(hsnap, &pt)) { // must call this first
        do {
            if (!lstrcmpi(pt.szExeFile, ProcessName)) {
                CloseHandle(hsnap);
                return pt.th32ProcessID;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(hsnap, &pt));
    }
    CloseHandle(hsnap); // close handle on failure
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD pid = MyGetProcessId(TEXT("calc.exe"));
    std::cout << pid;
    if (pid == 0) { printf("error 1"); getchar(); }//error
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I've changed the function to not use a `std::string` any more, and using `lstrcmpi` means it will work as either an Ansi or Unicode build. As the commentators below have suggested, you really should be using Unicode these days.

Comment: strcmp() is iffy too, process names are not case sensitive.  And no elegance points for not using Unicode.

Comment: If you want to compare a `std::string` and a `const char *` just use `==`.

Comment: @HansPassant These are all comments for the OP, it's not my job to rewrite his code completely. If I switched it to unicode he would almost certainly come back and say it didn't work because the rest of his program is in ansi.

Comment: Yeah, sure, ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the c code, works fine on windows. Calling PID_GetProcessId with process name, returns process id of process name

```
int PID_GetProcessId(char * name, PDWORD pid)
{
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    UINT32 i;

    if (!EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
    {
        //Error 
    }

    /* Calculate how many process identifiers were returned. */
    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

   /* Print the name and process identifier for each process. */
    for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
        if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )
        {
            if(PID_PrintProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i], name ) == 1)
            {
               *pid = aProcesses[i];
               break;
            }
         }
    }
    return 0;
}

int PID_PrintProcessNameAndID(DWORD processID,char * name)
{

    char szProcessName[MAX_PATH];
    HANDLE hProcess=NULL;
    char buff[200]="";

    hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |PROCESS_VM_READ,FALSE, processID );
    /* Get the process name. */
    if (NULL != hProcess )
    {
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;

        if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded) )
        {
            GetModuleBaseNameA( hProcess, hMod, (LPSTR)szProcessName, sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
        }
    }
    if(lstrcmpiA(szProcessName, name) == 0) 
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}
```